# System.AggregateException Error When Publishing Website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I decided to publish the ASP.NET MVC project to test it locally using *IIS Manager*. Therefore, after opening the necessary windows features, I created a new folder in the `C:\inetpub\` directory on *IIS Manager*:

[image]

In the *Visual Studio IDE* I right clicked on the solution and clicked **"Publish..."** and specified that the target was **"Folder"**:

[image]

When I clicked the <kbd>Next</kbd> button, I specified in the next window that the **"Target"** location was the `C.\inetpub\TechnologyArticle` directory. Then when I clicked the **"Publish..."** in the *Visual Studio IDE*, I encountered an error that I did not receive in `Debug` mode:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.

---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.

---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.
```

How can I solve this problem? Is the reason why I got this error in *Release mode*, which I did not receive in *Debug mode*, due to programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is not due to programming. The reason for this error is trying to publish the website in the `C:\inetpub\` directory, which is made visible and/or created by a service that you have activated by **"Turn Windows features on or off"** to publish the ASP.NET website locally. The user has no right to modify the `C:\inetpub\` directory. Therefore, the current user's right to modify the `C:\inetpub\` directory must be declared manually in the Windows 10 operating system.

When the ASP.NET website is published, the project outputs (such as *.dll files, style files, scripts, Views) compiled in Release mode will be extracted to the target directory, so the user must have the right to write to the `C:\inetpub` directory.

To resolve this issue, follow the steps below:

- Open the properties of the `C:\inetpub` folder (With the folder selected, use the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> shortcut).
- Switch to the Security tab and click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.
- Define `"Full Control"` right for current user and confirm settings by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
- You repeat the publish procedure to publish your website.

[image]